# angular get запрос

Tags: http, angular, get

проблема заключается в том, что я не получаю данные с сервера на клиенте, на постмен данные отправляются, я думаю, что скорее всего проблема заключается в url который я отправляю через гет запрос в angular

```
 name: string = "";
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

 }

 search(name : string) {
   console.log(name);
   this.http.get('http://localhost/WebTestServer/Ping/абв')
     .subscribe((response) => {
       this.response = response;
       console.log(this.response);
     })
 }


   <input type="text" (input)="inputHandler($event)">
    <button (click)="search(name)">
      Отправить гет
    </button>
    <div *ngIf="response">
    <p>Текст: {{response.data}}</p>
    </div>
```

[image: Результат запроса]
[image: Результат с постмана]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _я не получаю данные с сервера на клиенте_ а что приходит то? На картинке из браузера только заголовки показаны

Comment: ничего не приходит, я пытаюсь вывести данные на клиенте, а их нет и в результате запроса, в response пишет что данные не найдены

Comment: ну раз красным отображается, то наверное ошибка и никак не 200 код